# Add customiser controls directly to a panel

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm using the customiser and I'm making use of the **Panels** feature added in version 4.0.

I like that you can easily add **Sections** to **Panels**, but I'd like to also add **Controls** directly to **Panels** -

```
Panel -> Contact Us
    Control -> Teleohone number
    Control -> Emial address
    Section -> PHP Mailer settings
        Control -> SMTP host
        Control -> Debug
```

I wish to add several additional settings, the above is just an example of the structure I wish to use.

I've tried simply specifying the `panel` attribute in lieu of `section` when I add the **Control**, but to no avail.

I've created a [PasteBin containing some example code](http://pastebin.com/GL90SGW6).  Is there a way that I can achieve my desired results?

Comment: sidenote: use costumizer for front-end configuration, you should try to not overload it with options that are not FE related like SMTP.

Comment: I know that and you know that, but users ask "why are the options in two different places?"  This is a fairly small install, so with neatly arranged controls it won't overload the panel and won't result in the loss of ease-of-use.

Comment: well, no disrespect but giving bad UX to a user when you actually know it is wrong, is not something that a good developer does. In the end bad decision might come and hunt you when you get the phone calls to explain where is the SMTP configured.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - It's hardly a bad user experience; all configuration in one place.  And something a good developer always does is listen to the client, so when I'm asked to ensure that all configuration is available through the customiser (despite me explaining best practice), it's something that I do.  The beauty of being human is that we're all different; just because it's not the way you or I would do things, it doesn't mean that it's necessarily incorrect.

Comment: It is a UI placed where no one else expects to find it. There are conventions to how things should be done even if it is possible to do them differently.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - The clients expect to find it there because that's where they asked for it to go.  This site is not going to be for public consumption, those who will administer it have instructed me to set it up how they want.  There is one thing I don't know how to do (this question), so all I am looking to do is make my clients happy.

Comment: @DavidGard did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I've moved on to a new job since then so cannot check, but I don't believe I ever did find away I'm afraid.